# Soft raid 1 slow (disk fail?)

Tags: software-raid

I am running a server with Software Raid 1 and it is used solely for backup purposes using Idera/R1Soft. The last few days, the backups have been generated extremely slowly, so I am starting to wonder whether there are disk issues. However I am unsure whether this is the case, so hopefully someone can help me diagnose the issue.

Below is a lot of information of the disks, let me know if anything else is needed. Does these drives seem healthy, or what seems to be the issue? The backup software saves to the /home/ partition so this is probably where the issue lies.

If one of the disks is faulty, I need to send the server provider proof of this, what do I send?

Many thanks!

mdadm.conf

```
DEVICES /dev/[hs]d*
ARRAY /dev/md/0  metadata=1.0 UUID=77f79cbb:769b739a:61e3078d:baa387d3 name=rescue:0
ARRAY /dev/md/1  metadata=1.0 UUID=07982091:3873fa5c:5308f9a4:7be6239d name=rescue:1
ARRAY /dev/md/2  metadata=1.0 UUID=9faef154:1550a09e:b8a9f3a5:792ec8f7 name=rescue:2
ARRAY /dev/md/3  metadata=1.0 UUID=21d130c8:d3d06125:80436cbf:f30ca896 name=rescue:3
```

/proc/mdstat

```
Personalities : [raid1] 
md1 : active raid1 sda2[0] sdb2[1]
      524224 blocks super 1.0 [2/2] [UU]

md0 : active raid1 sda1[0] sdb1[1]
      8388596 blocks super 1.0 [2/2] [UU]

md3 : active raid1 sda4[0] sdb4[1]
      1847609660 blocks super 1.0 [2/2] [UU]
      [>....................]  check =  1.5% (28544512/1847609660) finish=30485.4min speed=994K/sec
      bitmap: 6/14 pages [24KB], 65536KB chunk

md2 : active raid1 sda3[0] sdb3[1]
      1073741688 blocks super 1.0 [2/2] [UU]
        resync=DELAYED

unused devices: <none>
```

lsblk

```
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda       8:0    0  2.7T  0 disk  
├─sda1    8:1    0    8G  0 part  
│ └─md0   9:0    0    8G  0 raid1 [SWAP]
├─sda2    8:2    0  512M  0 part  
│ └─md1   9:1    0  512M  0 raid1 /boot
├─sda3    8:3    0    1T  0 part  
│ └─md2   9:2    0 1024G  0 raid1 /
├─sda4    8:4    0  1.7T  0 part  
│ └─md3   9:3    0  1.7T  0 raid1 /home
└─sda5    8:5    0    1M  0 part  
sdb       8:16   0  2.7T  0 disk  
├─sdb1    8:17   0    8G  0 part  
│ └─md0   9:0    0    8G  0 raid1 [SWAP]
├─sdb2    8:18   0  512M  0 part  
│ └─md1   9:1    0  512M  0 raid1 /boot
├─sdb3    8:19   0    1T  0 part  
│ └─md2   9:2    0 1024G  0 raid1 /
├─sdb4    8:20   0  1.7T  0 part  
│ └─md3   9:3    0  1.7T  0 raid1 /home
└─sdb5    8:21   0    1M  0 part
```

smartctl -a /dev/sda4

```
smartctl 6.2 2013-07-26 r3841 [x86_64-linux-3.10.0-123.20.1.el7.x86_64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-13, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Seagate Barracuda 7200.14 (AF)
Device Model:     ST3000DM001-1CH166
Serial Number:    Z1F0S2S6
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000c50 04dc90878
Firmware Version: CC43
User Capacity:    3,000,592,982,016 bytes [3.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    7200 rpm
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 4
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Sun May  3 11:44:10 2015 CEST

==> WARNING: A firmware update for this drive may be available,
see the following Seagate web pages:
http://knowledge.seagate.com/articles/en_US/FAQ/207931en
http://knowledge.seagate.com/articles/en_US/FAQ/223651en

SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (  575) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x73) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    No Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   1) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 324) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x3085) SCT Status supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 10
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000f   117   099   006    Pre-fail  Always       -       162055184
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0003   092   092   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -       9
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   036    Pre-fail  Always       -       24
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000f   077   050   030    Pre-fail  Always       -       43512399126
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   074   074   000    Old_age   Always       -       23095
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   097    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -       9
183 Runtime_Bad_Block       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
184 End-to-End_Error        0x0032   100   100   099    Old_age   Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
188 Command_Timeout         0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0 0 0
189 High_Fly_Writes         0x003a   075   075   000    Old_age   Always       -       25
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0022   068   062   045    Old_age   Always       -       32 (Min/Max 25/33)
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       6
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   097   097   000    Old_age   Always       -       7646
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   032   040   000    Old_age   Always       -       32 (0 21 0 0 0)
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0010   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x003e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
240 Head_Flying_Hours       0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       23095h+14m+28.598s
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       130844533886
242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       310965085514

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%     20851         -
# 2  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%     20833         -
# 3  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%     20827         -
# 4  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%     20822         -
# 5  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%         5         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

smartctl -a /dev/sdb4

```
smartctl 6.2 2013-07-26 r3841 [x86_64-linux-3.10.0-123.20.1.el7.x86_64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-13, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Toshiba 3.5" HDD DT01ACA...
Device Model:     TOSHIBA DT01ACA300
Serial Number:    94KK14MGS
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000039 ff4e3eda1
Firmware Version: MX6OABB0
User Capacity:    3,000,592,982,016 bytes [3.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    7200 rpm
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 4
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Sun May  3 11:45:48 2015 CEST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x84) Offline data collection activity
                    was suspended by an interrupting command from host.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (22365) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x5b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   1) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 373) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x003d) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000b   100   100   016    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  2 Throughput_Performance  0x0005   140   140   054    Pre-fail  Offline      -       69
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0007   100   100   024    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       2
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   005    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000b   100   100   067    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  8 Seek_Time_Performance   0x0005   124   124   020    Pre-fail  Offline      -       33
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       2268
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   060    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       2
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       4
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       4
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0002   181   181   000    Old_age   Always       -       33 (Min/Max 25/36)
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0008   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x000a   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%        24         -
# 2  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%         5         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Comment: Look at the output you posted from /proc/mdstat.. does anything catch your eye?

Comment: Seems like the raid is re-syncing? What causes this and why is it taking so long? Can I speed up the process?

Comment: There has been some error in the array, and RAID is doing its job and fixes it :)

Comment: IMHO it's not a resync, it's a check. E.g. Debian schedules this at the beginning of each month on Sunday to prevent latent errors biting you. This reads all disk blocks (ensuring that they are readable), and read errors may be corrected by calculating the correct block data and rewriting the block (possibly causing the disk to replace the bad sector with a spare). Downside is indeed that this action slows down normal disk IO, however in my experience it's really worth it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your md3 array is resyncing, that's why it is slow. 
Based on your smartctl output, sda will fail soon.

```
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000f   117   099   006    Pre-fail  Always       -       162055184
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0003   092   092   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -       9
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   036    Pre-fail  Always       -       24
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000f   077   050   030    Pre-fail  Always       -       43512399126
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   074   074   000    Old_age   Always       -       23095
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   097    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -
```

See all the Pre-fail types?
If I were you, I'd change that disk ASAP.

Comment: I disagree about it failing soon. The meaning of those values is really only known by the manufacturer, and is used as input to the SMART health test. As both disks report "SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED" I wouldn't worry.

Comment: Well, I'd love to agree with you, but the server is re-syncing (or resynced) already, so there is something wrong - and the SMART also puts it to pre-fail. (Ok, there is a chance that the disk will not fail, but I think @azarat has to decide what about the budget, which is the more worthful running on an unreliable disk, and risk raid failure / slowness, or change before it fails really.

Comment: (late reply, sorry guys). Actually the server provider agreed to change the disk based on the values. The server provider is a cheap one, and requires plenty of data to be sent to prove the drive is failing. I think it is safe to say the drive was actually failing. The drive was resycning once more before the disk was replaced, and now everything is running smoothly.

Comment: FWIW if you read the column headers, you'd see that pre-fail is the type of statistic that's collected, not the status... WHEN_FAILED is empty too.